# exclude file path name and grep values in to text file

Tags: linux, grep, find

I want to grep the "404" pages on my web server in access logs, tried the below command,

```
grep -irn "404" /var/log/httpd/www.abc.com.access_log > abc-404.txt
```

now i want the same text file, without ***ema8ketpl4ace9dmin*** names for that given paths.it mean didn't want to those paths.

i have tried --exclude option didn't working properly.

```
grep --exclude=ema8ketpl4ace9dmin > abc-404.txt
```

it's only give me empty text file.

Comment: Your second command contains no pattern to search for.

Comment: pattern means is that need to full path contains of  "emarketplace"

Comment: The only thing wrong with your second command is that you're using `grep` without any pattern to search for (like you're using `"404"` in your first command).

Comment: Noted with Thanks\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to involve second `grep` like this:

```
grep -irn "404" /var/log/httpd/www.abc.com.access_log|grep -v ema8ketpl4ace9dmin  > abc-404.txt
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you use the `-r` option (at least in your first example) since you apply the `grep` call to one file only.

For you second problem, I would suggest using `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
awk '$0 ~ /404/ && $0 !~ /ema8ketpl4ace9dmin/ {print}' /var/log/httpd/www.abc.com.access_log > abc-404.txt
```

This will instruct `awk` to print all lines where the expression "404" occurs, but *not* (`!~`) the expression "ema8ketpl4ace9dmin".

Note that "print" is the standard action for any line to which the rules apply, so you can actually omit it and simply say

```
awk '$0 ~ /404/ && $0 !~ /ema8ketpl4ace9dmin/' /var/log/httpd/www.abc.com.access_log > abc-404.txt
```